# R - What algorithm does geom_density() use and how to extract points/equation of curves?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know what is geom_density() exactly doing, so I justify the graph and if there is any way of extracting the function or points that generates for each of the curves being plotted.

Thanks

Comment: I found that stat_density() allows you to set parameters. So probably that answers the first part. Still want to know if the equation or points can be extracted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Typing `get("compute_group", ggplot2::StatDensity)` (or, formerly, `get("calculate", ggplot2:::StatDensity)`) will get you the algorithm used to calculate the density. (At root, it's a call to `density()` with `kernel="gaussian"` the default.)

The points used in the plot are invisibly returned by `print.ggplot()`, so you can access them like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating))
m <- m + geom_density()
p <- print(m)
head(p$data[[1]], 3)
#           y      x   density   scaled  count PANEL group ymin      ymax
# 1 0.0073761 1.0000 0.0073761 0.025917 433.63     1     1    0 0.0073761
# 2 0.0076527 1.0176 0.0076527 0.026888 449.88     1     1    0 0.0076527
# 3 0.0078726 1.0352 0.0078726 0.027661 462.81     1     1    0 0.0078726


## Just to show that those are the points you are after, 
## extract and use them to create a lattice xyplot 
library(gridExtra)
library(lattice)
mm <- xyplot(y ~x, data=p$data[[1]], type="l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

As suggested in other answers, you can access the ggplot points using `print.ggplot()`. However, `print()`-ing code also prints the ggplot object, which may not be desired.

You can get extract the ggplot object data, *without printing the plot*, using `ggplot_build()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2movies)

m <- ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating))
m <- m + geom_density()
p <- ggplot_build(m)  # <---- INSTEAD OF `p <- print(m)`
head(p$data[[1]], 3)
#             y        x     density     scaled    count     n PANEL group ymin
# 1 0.007376115 1.000000 0.007376115 0.02591684 433.6271 58788     1    -1    0
# 2 0.007652653 1.017613 0.007652653 0.02688849 449.8842 58788     1    -1    0
# 3 0.007872571 1.035225 0.007872571 0.02766120 462.8127 58788     1    -1    0


# Just to show that those are the points you are after, extract and use them 
# to create a lattice xyplot 
library(lattice)
m2 <- xyplot(y ~x, data=p$data[[1]], type="l")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(m, m2, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Megatron, that is exactly what I was looking for!