# Store the result of a plot() call to a variable without sending to current graphics device

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

This is really one of two questions - either:

1) How do I store the result of a print() call [i.e. `x <- print(something)` ] **without** sending anything to current graphics output?
-or-

2) Is there a function or method in ggplot that will store a plot() call to a variable **without** calling `plot()` directly? `ggplotGrob` is in the ballpark, but a `ggplotGrob` object doesn't return a list with `$data` in it the same way you get when you store the result of `print()` to a variable.

I'm using a technique picked up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394321/r-what-algorithm-does-geom-density-use-and-how-to-extract-points-equation-of) SO answer to pull out the points of a geom_density curve, and then using that data to generate some annotations.  I've outlined the issue below -- when I call this as a function, I get the undesired intermediate plot object in my pdf, along with the final plot.  The goal is to get rid of that undesired plot; given that base `hist()` has a `plot = FALSE` option I was hopeful that someone who knows something more about R viewports would be able to fix my `plot()` call (solution #1), but any solution is fine, frankly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

demo <- function (df) {
  p <- ggplot(
    df
   ,aes(
      x = rating
    )
  ) + 
  geom_density()

  #plot the object so we can access $data
  render_plot <- plot(p + ggtitle("Don't want this plot"))

  #grab just the DF for the density line
  density_df <- render_plot$data[[1]]

  #get the maximum density value
  max_y <- ddply(density_df, "group", summarise, y = max(y))

  #join that back to the data to find the matching row
  anno <- join(density_df, max_y, type = 'inner')

  #use this to annotate
  p <- p + annotate(
    geom = 'text'
   ,x = anno$x
   ,y = anno$y
   ,label = round(anno$density, 3)
  ) + 
  ggtitle('Keep this plot')

  return(p)
}

#call to demo outputs an undesired plot to the graphics device
ex <- demo(movies[movies$Comedy ==1,])

plot(ex)

#this is problematic if you are trying to make a PDF

  #a distinct name for the pdf to avoid filesystem issues
  unq_name <- as.character(format(Sys.time(), "%X"))
  unq_name <- gsub(':', '', unq_name)

pdf(paste(unq_name , '.pdf', sep=''))

  p <- demo(movies[movies$Drama ==1,])
  print(p)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ggplot_build`:

```
render_plot <- ggplot_build(p + ggtitle("Don't want this plot"))
```