# #NOT DUPLICATED!!# How can I get kernel density value from geom_density output in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[THIS QUESTION IS NOT DUPLICATED! PREVIOUS ANSWER NEVER FUNCTION IN CURRENT VERSION GGPLOT2 V.3]
Is it possible to yield y value of geom_density in specific x value from following script?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
p<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Petal.Length))+
   geom_density(aes(colour=Species),position="identity")
p
```

[image: output]
I tried [R - What algorithm does geom_density() use and how to extract points/equation of curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394321/r-what-algorithm-does-geom-density-use-and-how-to-extract-points-equation-of) . but in my environment R3.5.1 and ggplot 3.1.0, that just return iris data instead of kernel density.

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394321/r-what-algorithm-does-geom-density-use-and-how-to-extract-points-equation-of did not work in my env. R 3.4.4

Comment: I tried with R3.5.1 and also not work

Comment: I found that previous answer showed by @josh-obrien is work in ggplot2 version 2, but not in version3.