# How calculate probabillity of density plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, diagram

I have following question: Is it possible to calculate a probabillity of a density plot?

So for example, I have following data frame

```
 test<- data.frame(
  Gruppe = rep(c("Aktien","Aktien"), 
               times=c(136, 37)),
  Zufriedenheit = c(f_keineErf, f_Erf))
```

and i plot a density plot, with de ggplot function:

```
 ggplot(test, aes(x=Zufriedenheit)) +geom_density()
```

How can I calculate the probability for example getting a value above 70?

Thank you!

Comment: Judging from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394321/r-what-algorithm-does-geom-density-use-and-how-to-extract-points-equation-of) you can get the points used to make the `geom_density` plot. You can work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not included in the question, so let's make up a small random sample:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10))
```

Now we can create a density plot as per your example:

```r
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) + 
  geom_density() +
  xlim(c(-5, 5))

p
```

[image]

Now, we can actually find the x and y coordinates of this line using the base R function `density` and extracting its x and y components into a data frame:

```r
dens <- density(df$x)
d    <- data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)

head(d)
#>           x            y
#> 1 -3.157056 0.0009453767
#> 2 -3.144949 0.0010145927
#> 3 -3.132841 0.0010870523
#> 4 -3.120733 0.0011665920
#> 5 -3.108625 0.0012488375
#> 6 -3.096517 0.0013382316
```

We can see plotting this as a red dashed `geom_line` it is the same as `geom_density`:

```r
p + geom_line(data = d, aes(x, y), col = "red", linetype = 2, size = 2)
```

[image]

Now suppose we want to know the probability of having a value of more than one. We can show the area we are interested in like this:

```r
p + geom_area(data = d[d$x >= 1,], aes(x, y), fill = "red")
```

[image]

Since the x values are all equally spaced in our data frame `d`, then the red area's proportion of the area under the line is a simple ratio of the sum of all y values at x values greater than one to the grand sum of y:

```r
sum(d$y[d$x > 1])/sum(d$y)
#> [1] 0.1599931
```

So the probability of getting an x value of > 1 is 0.15999, or 16%

<sup>Created on 2020-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I nedded :-)